# How many $\text{watt}$ are required to obtain $500°$$\text{C}$?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-radiation

I am using two $1000$ $\text{watt}$ heating elements in a cylindrical chamber of volume $7500$ $\text{cm}^3$ with a limited opening at two sides. The cylinder has a radius of $6$ $\text{inch}$. How can we attain $500°$$\text{C}$ or more in this chamber within a matter of seconds? Is it possible to attain this temperature by the addition of extra heating elements?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange :) I am voting to close this question as it appears to be about engineering rather than physics.

Comment: I think it does relate to physics, because its answer requires attention to several important physical principles.

Comment: To answer this question, you need to know the thermal conductivity of the chamber walls and the total heat capacity and conductivity of the object you intend to heat inside the chamber. Do you have these numbers at hand?

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't enough information given in the question to formulate a specific answer.  Some missing information is:

1. Is the chamber insulated?  How good is the insulation?
2. What material is the cylindrical chamber made of, and what are the chamber's dimensions?
3. What is inside the chamber, besides the heating element itself?
4. What is the heating element made of?

These are important for an answer to your question because, for example, if the chamber is insulated perfectly and is made of infinitesimally thin material, and if the heating element is simply a laser beam passing through a tiny hole in the chamber wall, and if the chamber contains nothing but vacuum, the temperature will rise almost instantly.  The issue is "thermal inertia": the amount of heat (watts x seconds) required to raise the temperature of the chamber and its contents (*and* the heating element itself) by one degree C.

Comment: Indeed. For example, it takes less than a watt to make a bicycle light filament glow.